# jQuery is unable to run the .click event on dynamically generated button or p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to add a feature of autocomplete, now whatever the result it's returning I'm outputting in the form of a button, but as soon as I apply the click event on dynamically generated button, it doesn't work. Here is my piece of code :

```
// controller
function autocomplete()
    {
        $string = "";
        $query = $this->db->select('p_sku')->from('fr_products')->like('p_sku',$_POST['sku']);
        $results = $query->get()->result();
        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            $string .= '<p id='.$result->p_sku.'>'.$result->p_sku.'</p> ';
        }

        echo $string;
    }
    function show_autocomplete()
    {
        $this->load->view('testing/auto');
    }

// view


    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sku').keyup(function(){
            var len = $('#sku').val().length;
            if(len >= 2)
            {
                var value = $('#sku').val();
                $.post(
                    '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/testing/autocomplete',
                    {sku:value},
                    function(data){
                        $('#feedback').html(data);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
        $('p').click(function(){
            alert('click');
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" name="sku" placeholder="SKU1,SKU2,SKU3" id="sku"/>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind events to elements that are automatically generated after the script is run, you need to use the `on` jQuery function. In your case, you can use this code:

```
$('#feedback').on('click', 'p', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use <kbd>[Event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)</kbd>

try like this:

```
$("#feedback").on( "click", "p", function(){
  alert("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$(document).delegate( "#feedback p","click", function(){
  alert("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this this will works.**

```
    $(function(){})
    $("#feedback").live( "click", "p", function(){
  alert("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on to make activate click event when tags/buttons created dynamically.

```
$('#feedback').on('click', 'p', function() {
        alert('ButtonCreated');
    });
```